# Getting Error 26 in SSMS when trying to connect to my Docker instance

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I'm trying to spin up a SQL instance of which I'm an admin so that I can follow the exercises in a Microsoft T-SQL book. I'm trying to connect to my `Docker SQL` using the password that I set up. I'm using what I believe is a default username `("sa")`. I've tried putting the server name with and without the port number. I have provided the error below that I receive when I attempt to connect to the server using the credentials of the screenshot above. I have also attempted to add a rule to my firewall to resolve this error but was unsuccessful thus far.

Let me know if there is any other information I should provide. Thank you all for your time.

[image: Docker and SSMS]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please help to share the error in the content rather than the image

Comment: @Ashok I have edited the question to state when I get the error.

Comment: are you connecting from Windows machine A to Windows machine B?

Comment: @Ashok I am connecting to a Docker container with a SQL image on the same Windows machine I am using SSMS on.

Comment: Change your .\SQLEXPRESS,and add your SQL express name only and it works for me

Comment: Basically, you've got the wrong server\instance in the connection string

Comment: @ashok Thank you for your assistance. However, I am not sure what .\SQLEXPRESS is or how to obtain a SQL express name.

Comment: Can you please share the connection string code snippet

Comment: Or else try to start SQL server manually if not automatically started

Comment: @Ashok Can you clarify how I can obtain the connection string code snippet?

Comment: First, try to start SQL server manually if not automatically started

Comment: @Ashok OK. I have clicked "stop" on the sqltest docker container. Then I clicked "run." It is currently running.

Comment: @MeowMeow Have you tried just using `localhost,1401`? If that doesn't work, change your `-p` argument on your container to use `-p 1433:1433` and then connect with `localhost`

Comment: @dfundako I think most people on here are assuming I have a lot of experience I do not have. I do not know what a -p argument is aside from it probably has something to do with a PS command which I am not using. Are you saying I should type in `localhost, 1401` into the SSMS login screen?

Comment: @MeowMeow Ahh ok. I'll add an entire answer. Hold please.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your docker container, try and use the following, but use your own password, container name, image name, etc. But try and leave the port mapping, or the `-p` arg as is. This comes straight from the MS docs:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Or in one line:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)

Once that container is up, open SSMS and in the connection prompt, use the following:
[image]

By just using `localhost`, that assumes you're trying to connect to port 1433. If you change your port mapping in your container command, you use the comma and port number after localhost, like this: `localhost, 1456`

Comment: I ran that command in Powershell and got the error that "-p" is not recognized as a cmdlet.

https://ibb.co/tpV6qKk

Comment: @MeowMeow Try putting it all on the same line and remove the backslash values.

Comment: Currently it is downloading an image from the internet even though I already had an image on docker. It claimed it was unable to find that image locally. It is still downloading.

Comment: Followed directions and got the same error. - https://ibb.co/njxQyzm